# Meaning of "aesthetic lighting feature" in context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> High-end retailers such as Tiffany and Hermes do their best to stimulate all the senses in building their brand experience, which may include **aesthetic lighting features** and enchanting aromas.

What does "aesthetic lighting feature" mean in this context?

Comment: No idioms involved. The whole is exactly the sum of its parts. You can look up the meaning word for word in a dictionary of your choice.

Answer (score 2):

It means that their lighting has features that make it look cool or good.  Your basic marketing phrase that really means nothing.

Comment: But has the perennial 'buy me' subtext. Oops, that's what 'basic marketing phrase' means, isn't it.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Opposed to the high end shops that focus on ugly lights that annoy you and smell bad.

Answer (score 2):

*Aesthetic* = pleasing, beautiful.

*Lighting* = the way light shines on objects.

*Features* = functional things, applications, perks (basically a rather vague but positive word).

So this means they have installed certain lights to shine on the interior of the shop and its products so as to make everything look more pleasing to the eye. The wording is typical for business and advertising: verbose and hollow.